# Culling interior triangles

Tags: language-agnostic, geometry, triangulation

I have an array of thousands of quads; 4-sided 3D polygons. All I know are the coordinates of the quad corners.

A subset of these quads define the closed outer shell of a 3D shape. The remaining quads are on the inside of this closed solid.

How do I figure out which quads are part of the shell and which quads are part of the interior? This is not performance critical code.

---

Edit: Further constraints on the shape of the shell

- There are no holes inside the shape, it is a single surface.
- It contains both convex and concave portions.
- I have a few points which are known to be on the inside of the shell.

Comment: What is known about the shape?  One needs more than just the coordinates of the quads.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge for example.

Comment: Whatever you are doing sounds awesome.

Comment: Given that any four non-co-planar points form a quad, if I understand you aright, it's impossible to solve unless you have another constraint, like say having a convex shape.  Otherwise, it's impossible to tell whether a given boundary quad is part of the body or a hole.

Comment: Added further information about the shape.

Comment: Are the quads on the outer surface contiguous or are there gaps in the outer surface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be hard to implement if your shape self intersects, but if you can find one quad that you know is on the surface (possibly one furthest away from the centroid) then map out concentric circles of quads around it. Then find a continuous ring of quads outside that and so on, until you end up at the "opposite" side. If your quads intersect, or are internally connected, then that's more difficult. I'd try breaking apart those which intersect, then find all the possible smooth surfaces, and pick the one with the greatest internal volume.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. There are no self-intersections but the quads on the inside share edges with the shell quads.

Comment: Assuming you do manage to find an outermost quad, that should also tell you it's normal vector pointing out of the surface. When you compare neighbours, you should be able to work out their normals out of the surface too. If an edge happens to be shared between three quads - the one known to be on the surface plus two candidates, then the candidate with the smaller angle between it's normal and the normal of the known surface quad will also be a surface one, since the quad with the larger angle must be pushing into the solid.

Comment: that's a great approach to solving this problem. Just to add to your suggestion: The shell is basically a simple quad mesh that's folded in the 3D space. So, once you determined the 1st shell element, you can continue scanning for adjacent element in a "flood fill" manner.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

Calculate the normal vector of a quad (call this the 'current' quad).
Do an intersection test with that vector and all the remaining quads.
If it intersects another quad in the positive portion of the vector you know the current quad is an internal quad. Repeat for all the remaining quads.

This assumes the quads 'face' outward.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but it wouldn't work for concave shells. And I'm afraid the shell shape is totally freeform, with many concave and convex areas.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the intersection test? A correct test should handle concave quads.

Comment: Imagine a bowl with vertical sides. If you draw a vector out from the inner part of one side of the bowl, then it will intersect with quads on the other side of the bowl, even though it is on the surface.

Comment: Ah. If I can assume it's a closed surface change that to "count the intersections with the ray and if there are an odd number of them then it's an internal quad". That might not work if the internal quads are not a closed surface. It might also be better to decompose the quads to triangles. It would make the math easier and faster.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done quite easily if the shape is convex. When the shape is concave it is much harder.

In the convex case find the centroid by computing the average of all of the points. This gives a point that is in the interior for which the following property holds:

> If you project four rays from the
>   centroid to each corner of a quad you
>   define a pyramid cut into two parts,
>   one part contains space interior to
>   the shape and the other part defines
>   space that might be exterior to the
>   shape.

These two volumes give you a decision process to check if a quad is on the boundary or not. If any point from another quad occurs in the outside volume then the quad is not on the boundary and can be discarded as an interior quad.

Edit: Just seen your clarification above. In the harder case that the shape is concave then you need one of two things;

1. A description (parameterisation) of the shape that you can use to choose quads with, or
2. Some other property such as all of the boundary quads being contiguous

Further edit: Just realised that what you are describing would be a concave hull for the points. Try looking at some of the results in [this search page](http://www.google.com/search?q=concave+hull+algorithm).

Comment: Your wiki link is for _convex_ hull

Answer (score 2):

Consider that all of the quads live inside a large sealed box.  Pick one quad.  Do raytracing; treat that quad as a light source, and treat all other quads as reflective and fuzzy, where a hit to a quad will send light in all directions from that surface, but not around corners.

If no light rays hit the external box after all nodes have had a chance to be hit, treat that quad as internal.

If it's convex, or internal quads didn't share edges with external quads, there are easier ways.

Comment: Or do the opposite: render the object as you fly around it, and delete the polygons which were never displayed

Comment: @Tom Sirgedas: You won't have direct line-of-sight on all polygons from the outside of the box, since it can be a highly convex shape.  That said, if the polygons are still diffusely reflective, yeah, absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to make your problem easier by reducing the number of quads that you have to deal with.

You know that some of the quads form a closed shell.  Therefore, those quads are connected at their edges.  If three mutually adjacent edges of a quad (that is, the edges form a closed loop) overlap the edge of another quad, then these quads might be part of the shell (these mutually adjacent edges serve as the boundary of a 2D region; let's call that region the "connected face" of the quad).  Make a list of these "shell candidates".  Now, look through this list and throw out any candidate who has an edge that does not overlap with another candidate (that is, the edge overlaps an edge of a quad that is not in the list).  Repeat this culling process until you are no longer able to remove any quads.  What you have left should be your shell.  Create a "non-shell quads" list containing all of the quads not in the "shell" list.

Draw a bounding box (or sphere, ellipse, etc) around this shell.  Now, look through your list of non-shell quads, and throw out any quads that lie *outside* of the bounding region.  These are definitely not in the interior.

Take the remaining non-shell quads.  These may or may not be in the interior of the shape.  For each of these quads, draw lines perpendicular to the quad from the center of each face that end on the surface of the bounding shape.  Trace each line and count how many times the line crosses through the "connected face" of a quad in your shell list.  If this number is odd, then that vertex lies in the interior of the shape.  If it is even, the vertex is on the exterior.  You can determine whether a quad is inside or outside based on whether its vertices are inside or outside.